# Как удалить конкретный Point в библиотеке yandex map kit 3.0?

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Всем добрый день, добавляю метку (point) на карту, после нажатия на кнопку определения местоположения эта метка должна удалиться и добавиться в другом месте на карте с другими координатами, ниже код

```
mainPoint = new Point(geoPosition.getLatitude(), geoPosition.getLongitude());
mapView.getMap().move(
                    new CameraPosition(mainPoint, 15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                    new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
                    null);
            mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(mainPoint,ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.mygeo_light_icon));
```

так я добавляю метку на карту, всё работает.
Дальше пытаюсь удалить именно её с карты и добавить новую с обновленными координатами

```
mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().remove((MapObject) mainPoint);
mainPoint = new Point(geoPosition.getLatitude(), geoPosition.getLongitude());
```

Возникает два вопроса :

1. Можно ли не удалять метку а просто переместить его с новыми
   координатами ?
2. Если отпадает первый пункт, то как удалить конкретную метку ? В моем варианте не работает из за того что Point невозможно
   преобразовать в MapObject

Comment: mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().getParent().clear()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переместить точечный объект, конечно, можно. Достаточно сохранить результат вызова addPlacemark и вызвать у него метод setGeometry: https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/map/PlacemarkMapObject-docpage/#method_detail__method_setGeometry__Point

Comment: а можно продемонстрировать как то? я про переместить точечный объект

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести пример кода, как запомнить результат вызова addPlacemark.
Потому что, не удалить его не переместить через какое то время не возможно, в виду мегкой ссылки объект перестает существововать.
Спасибо!