# Удаление или перемещение метки. Yandex MapKit Android

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Добавляю метку на карту следующим способом:

```
mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(new Point(54.513553, 36.259944), ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.my_geo_icon));
```

После мне необходимо переставить метку в другое место. Я вижу два способа: переместить имеющуюся метку, либо удалить имеющуюся и добавить новую. Не могу найти как реализовать хотя бы один из вариантов. Помогите примером, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено на основе [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846998/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-point-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5-yandex-map-kit-3-0).

Задаю метку и сохраняю её в переменную:

```
private PlacemarkMapObject Now_Geoposition;
..........
Now_Geoposition = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(new Point(54.513553, 36.259944), ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.my_geo_icon));
```

Меняю координаты метки (перемещаю имеющуюся, не удаляя):

```
Now_Geoposition.setGeometry(new Point(54.193961, 37.615977));
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы просто переставить метку действительно можно воспользоваться `setGeometry(…), как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1261032/544874)

А если надо именно удалить, это делается так:

```
private PlacemarkMapObject placemark;
......
placemark = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(…)
......
mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().remove(placemark)
```